# How can I preview a Gist in GitHub?

Tags: github, gist

Like a Preview tab when your write an issue. Do GitHub Gists have it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a standard repository and then [set this up to be a GitHub page](https://pages.github.com/).

[Example](https://github.com/nilslindemann/Hello_World_With_Preview)

Answer (score 0):

There is https://gistpreview.github.io.

I found it quite handy to post the link (including gist ID) into the first gist comment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[As of November 2021](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-11-17-preview-the-markdown-rendering-of-gists/), there is a preview tab when editing a Markdown Gist.

The Gist's file extension has to be set to `.md` for the tab to be displayed.